# $AA^{t}=A^{t}A$ in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M$ be a square matrix such that $M_{i,j}=c$ if $i\not=j$ and $d$ if $i=j$. Also, $0<c<d$ (note that this is a strict inequality). That is, $M$ look like this:

$\begin{pmatrix}d & c & \ldots & \ldots & c & c\\c & d & \ldots & \ldots & c & c\\\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\c & c & \ldots & \ldots & d & c\\c & c & \ldots & \ldots & c & d\\\end{pmatrix}$

If $A$ is a square matrix such that $AA^{t}=M$ is it necessarily the case that $A^{t}A=M$?

(we are working in $\mathbb{R}$; actually the actual question is meant for $\mathbb{Q}$ but I am trying to gain some insight by looking at the easier situation)

This is clearly true if we allow $c=0$, and is clearly false if we allow $c=d$. But I have not been able to do it in this case. I suspect it is false but have not been able to find a counterexample.

Comment: Do we talk about square matrices $A$? If not you may end up having different dimensions. In that case it woulnd't work for $c=0,d=0$ because take $\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ then $AA^T=I_3$ but $A^TA=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Ah sorry should be square matrix, I will clarify that.

Comment: Quote "clearly false if we allow c=d"

But that is not the case as there are counter examples...

Comment: @johannesvalks: when one talk about a "necessary" statement, "false" means that it is false in at least one case, not false in every case.

Comment: Then please explain what you mean by

"clearly false if we allow c=d"...

Comment: @johannesvalks: it means the counterexample is obvious. Just take $A$ with the first column filled with $\sqrt{d}$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: Then I have misunderstood that particular part. Sorry about that and the confusion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a two-dimensional counterexample:

$$A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 5\\3 & 4\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: Yep! One counterexample disproves the assumption...

Answer (score 3):

I think perhaps this serves as a counterexample.

If $c < \frac{d}{n-1}$, then the matrix is Hermitian and strictly diagonally dominant with positive entries, and hence is positive semi-definite. Therefore, it admits a unique Cholesky factorization, $U^TU = M$ (equivalently $LL^T = M$). However, it is not necessarily true that $UU^T = M$. For example, let $$M = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 &3 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Then, $$U \approx \begin{pmatrix}1.7321 &   0.5774   & 0.5774\\
         0    & 1.6330    & 0.4082 \\
         0         & 0    & 1.5811 \end{pmatrix}$$

and it can be seen that $U^TU = M$ but not $UU^T$.

Comment: This works.  In general, it should be noted that upper triangular matrices satisfy $U^TU = UU^T$ if and only if they are diagonal.

Comment: since the decomposition is unique if $M$ is positive definite $U^TU = M = UU^T$ only is true if $U^T=U$

Answer (score -1):

Even for the case $c=d$ it can be valid, as

$$
\textbf{A} = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\sqrt{c/n}&\sqrt{c/n}&\cdots&\sqrt{c/n}\\
\sqrt{c/n}&\sqrt{c/n}&\cdots&\sqrt{c/n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\sqrt{c/n}&\sqrt{c/n}&\cdots&\sqrt{c/n}\\
\end{array}
\right],
$$

has the property that

$$
\textbf{A} \textbf{A}^T = \textbf{A}^T \textbf{A} = \textbf{M},
$$

where

$$
\textbf{M} = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
c&c&\cdots&c\\
c&c&\cdots&c\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
c&c&\cdots&c\\
\end{array}
\right],
$$